# How to assert a buttons onClick is assigned to a Function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

this should be really basic, I am simply trying to assert in my test that a buttons onClick prop is equal to the function 'scrollToTop'. I am struggling with the syntax.

currently, my test is

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<ContactFooter/>)
  });

 it('has a button that directs the user to the top of the page', () => {
    const scrollToTop = Function
    expect(wrapper.find('.up-btn').props().onClick).toBe(scrollToTop)
  })
```

and the error reads

```
Expected: [Function Function]
Received: [Function scrollToTop]
```

how can I correct this??

```
import { animateScroll as scroll} from 'react-scroll'

function ContactFooter() {

 function scrollToTop(){
   scroll.scrollToTop()
 }
  return(
    <div className="contact-footer d-flex justify-content-center" id="contact">
       <button className="up-btn" onClick={scrollToTop}>
          <img src={icon} alt="up"/>
        </button>
      </div>
  )
}
export default ContactFooter
```

Comment: Are you really testing that React correctly handles props? React is already very tested. This, IMO, isn't a very useful unit test for your code, but can you include your `ContactFooter` component code, and what `Function` is, so we can try to help?

Comment: @DrewReese, what would be a better way to do this?

Comment: It'd make more sense to test for *the* function, not that it is *a* function. Personally I'd just click it and see if the function was called--that way you're not tied to the specific function, which might change. Or drive a browser and check the scroll position, or... etc.

Comment: Right, provide a mocked callback, i.e. `onClickMock = jest.fn()`, pass that to the `onClick` prop of `ContactFooter`, and test that when clicked the callback it invoked, i.e. `.hasBeenCalled()`.

Comment: Ah, I see now, you aren't actually passing an onClick prop. Mock the `scroll` object and assert that `scrollToTop` was called. If you provide the `scroll` code we can help you mock that.

Comment: It's `toEqual(expect.any(Function))` but there's no much value in it. Just call it. Enzyme does this with `simulate`.

Comment: @DrewReese there is no scroll code, its a function thats straight out of the box with 'react-scroll'

Comment: You can mock `react-scroll`. I think this doc can help: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks